# How can I fix this error with slackr: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: r

I installed and am trying to use the slackr package with R.
I cannot get slackr_upload function to work.

```
slackr_upload(path, title = "Test",
             initial_comment = "No Comment", 
             channels = "#general",
             api_token = key)
```

The code runs without error, but produces no result.

When I run the following code:

```
a <- slackr_channels(api_token = key)
```

A list of channels is returned.

Comment: I strongly suspect that when I attempt to reproduce this that I will find that there will be a message saying object `path` not found.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "Mac ism."  I needed to correctly specify the pathname to the file.

I needed to set path <- ~/Doucments/ . . . /filename.png

That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
Adding the scopes as posted by "yonicd" in url (https://github.com/hrbrmstr/slackr/issues/89) fixed the issue for me.